# Add a certain amount of time to a current time and write it

Tags: android, time, addition

I'm using:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
```

with which i get a current time,

```
String sHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)
String sMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE)
```

What i need is to add e.g. 1 Hour 10 Minutes - store it in a variable and also Substract let's say 10 minutes and save that as an another variable. (I need to use them both in a `TextView`)

I've seen the `add();` method in Android documentation but I can't seem to understand how it works. Thanks

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The code you've posted won't compile, as `Calendar.get()` doesn't return a string. You should also note that calendar is mutable - it's not like each call to `add` returns a new calendar. So you'll need to create a *new* instance each time you want a separate variable for a different value. For example:

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

Calendar tmp = (Calendar) now.clone();
tmp.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 1);
tmp.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 10);
Calendar nowPlus70Minutes = tmp;

tmp = (Calendar) now.clone();
tmp.add(Calendar.MINUTE, -10);
Calendar nowMinus10Minutes = tmp;
```

If at all possible, I'd *strongly* recommend that you use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) instead of Calendar/Date - it's a *far* superior API. You may want to trim the time zones included with it, however, so that it's faster to get started and less overhead in your apk.

Comment: Can anyone tell what will happen if I try to add lets say 100 minutes? will it add it as 1 Hour 40 Minutes? or I have to convert my time to HH:mm format before adding it up?

Comment: @GeekWithGlasses: I would *strongly* advise you to get into the habit of experimenting for yourself. It's very easy to find out what happens if you add 100 minutes - just try it in a tiny console application. You'll learn a lot more that way than if we just tell you.

Answer (score 5):

You can simply call `System.currentTimeMillis() + INTERVAL`.

Where INTERVAL is the interval in milliseconds (for example:

```
public static final long INTERVAL = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24; // 1 day
```